# How do I pass the driver object around?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Updated to reflect the current issues!

---

I'm very very new to Python and am really struggling to structure my tests according to page object model (something which I can do in C#). I just can't figure out how to pass the driver object / if I'm even trying to solve the right problem! Please help.

For reference, here is the test file and the login page. When the test runs, it launches the browser then immediately fails because it can't find the emailField object.

"File "c:\Users\079382\Downloads\QA Technical Task 1\Grain Supplier Solution\grains\tests\tests.py", line 19, in 
loginPage.emailField.send_keys("admin@admin.com")
AttributeError: 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'emailField'"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pages.adminpage import AdminPage
from pages.loginpage import LoginPage

# def test_accessibility_tab_order_admin_page(self):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('http://localhost:8000/admin/')
driver.maximize_window()

loginPage = LoginPage(driver)

#Ensure that the field selected by default is the email field
assert driver.switch_to.active_element == loginPage.emailField
driver.find_element_by_id('djHideToolBarButton').click()

loginPage.emailField.send_keys("admin@admin.com")
loginPage.passwordField.send_keys("admin")
loginPage.loginButton.click()

adminPage = AdminPage(driver)
adminPage.checkTabOrder()

driver.quit()
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.basepage import BasePage

class LoginPage(BasePage):
    #login page methods
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

        # #login page elements
        emailField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="username"]')
        passwordField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="password"]')
        loginButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refined answer based on your new example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pages.adminpage import AdminPage
from pages.loginpage import LoginPage

# def test_accessibility_tab_order_admin_page(self):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('http://localhost:8000/admin/')
driver.maximize_window()

loginPage = LoginPage(driver)
loginPage.test()

#adminPage = AdminPage(driver)
#adminPage.checkTabOrder()

driver.quit()
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.basepage import BasePage

class LoginPage(BasePage):
    #login page methods
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

        # login page elements
        self.emailField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="username"]')
        self.passwordField = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="password"]')
        self.loginButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]')

    def test(self):
        # ensure that the field selected by default is the email field
        assert self.driver.switch_to.active_element == self.emailField
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('djHideToolBarButton').click()

        self.emailField.send_keys("admin@admin.com")
        self.passwordField.send_keys("admin")
        self.loginButton.click()
```

Comment: I'm unblocked, thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider using the page objects structure a possibility to "specialise" your tests by generalising functionality. Also ask yourself if in your example you actually need to keep the login page elements or you might just use them in the test function when needed as you currently only seem to be using each of them once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but it looks as if you have solved the problem of "how to pass the driver" to your page objects, but there are a few Python problems.
The key is that the `class BasePage` takes care of keeping track of the driver and the derived `class LoginPage(BasePage)` uses `BasePage` as expected.

The there are a few problems:

- The `class AdminPage` is missing its base class and should probably read `class AdminPage(BasePage)`.
- The code code of your classes must be in individual methods that each have a `self` argument and `driver` must be accessed as `self.driver`.

Have a look at the following canonical [example](https://www.online-python.com/um9DYRwla4):

```py
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class MainPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        
    def test(self):
        print(self.driver)

mainPage = MainPage(4711)
mainPage.test()
```

Comment: I only tried to answer your question about the overall structure of your code and not any specific selenium api call. If you need more help, you will need to post the exact code you are using, a possible example and the exact error messages you get.

Comment: I recommend updating the original question with all the needed information.

Comment: OK, I've made some reasonably drastic changes to try to make this follow the page object model, but it falls over in the same place. For some reason it's unable to find the first element that it's looking for and I'm assuming it's because it can't access the driver properly (but what do I know?). I've got the [latest version in here] (https://github.com/Keiggo/python-test-page-object-but-broken/tree/master/Grain%20Supplier%20Solution/grains/tests), if you wouldn't mind taking another look at it.

Comment: What error message do you get and where exactly?

Comment: You don't need to use page objects at all and you should first try to get the test itself working as a plain sequence of selenium api call and only later try to take advantage of the page object pattern.

Comment: Just updated the original post as per your excellent suggestion

Comment: I do have the test working as a plain sequence, in another repo. I just want to understand how I can restructure it

Comment: Your error is not related to selenium or the driver but just a problem with the way you use the Python classes. Try to get the example to work as a plain sequential Python script without classes at all and only then work on the page object structure.

Comment: I do have the test working as a sequential script here: https://github.com/Keiggo/python-test-ugly-but-working/blob/master/Grain%20Supplier%20Solution%20-%20working%20and%20ugly/grains/tests/tests.py I'm now trying to work on page object structure

Comment: The actual Python problem is caused by the fact that your code outside the class wants to access local variables inside the class. There is many ways on how to "fix" this but I personally recommend a different structure. Do all the work inside the class as I suggested in my example. If you look at the method `test` in my `MainPage` class, you would perform all the actions you are currently doing outside the class with `test`. I will post a new answer based on your new code.

Comment: You are my new favourite person. By a long way.

Comment: Thank you and please accept my answer and upvote all my feedback to show it ;-)

Comment: I have just posted a new answer that shows the structure I would suggest using. I'm not able to test the code outside your environment and hope I dd not miss anything, but the idea should be clear. Let me know if I missed something, so I can refine it.